# Python TypeHint: TypeVar dependency

Tags: python, type-hinting

I have defined a generic function using `TypeVar` to describe a process that has a common structure.

I want to get a value from data keyed by a `Literal` string like the following function.

```py
from typing import Literal, TypeVar

data: dict[Literal["cat"] | Literal["dog"], int] = {
    "cat": 0,
    "dog": 1,
}

Key = TypeVar("Key")
Value = TypeVar("Value")


def get_value(key: Key, data: dict[Key, Value]) -> Value:
    return data[key] # actualy more complex logic.


cat = get_value("cat", data)  # Collect! data has 'cat'
bird = get_value("bird", data)  # Wrong! data don't have 'bird', but pass type check :(
```

However, the type annotation seems to be interpreted as `Callable[[str, dict [str, int]], int]`.

I want to get the type annotation like `Callable[[Literal["cat", "dog"], dict[Literal["cat", "dog"], int]], int]`.

So, I tried to set `TypeVar` dependency like this, but error.

```py
Key = TypeVar("Key")
Value = TypeVar("Value")
Label = TypeVar("Label", Key) # TypeVar bound type cannot be generic

def get_value(label: Label, data: dict[Key, Value]) -> Value:
    return data[label]
```

### Question

How to set `TypeVar` dependency, or the another approach to set the type annotation.